# Colors not reversed when using coord_flip() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to build a bar plot and use `coord_flip()` in view to have horizontal bars.

I have also defined a customized color palette with 6 values

```
Custcolor <- (c("#702082","#00a0d2","#00c389","#63666a","#c110a0","#ffb81c","#702082","#00a0d2","#00c389")
```

I have successfully reversed the order of the bars after `coord_flip()`, but I don't see how to reverse the order of the colors at the same time, then keep the same colors to the same bars after reversing. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can manually reverse the color vector with the `rev` function where you use the vector.

```
rev(Custcolor)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm going to test.